# Create a list of components using data from a map of lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map in following structure.

```
const myMap = {
    "title1" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "n1"
        },
                {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "n2"
        }
    ],
    "title2" : [
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "name" : "n3"
        },
                {
            "id" : "4",
            "name" : "n4"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I am trying to run over above map and achieve a list of list of components as follows.

```
[
    [
        <MyComponent props={props}/>,
        <MyComponent props={props}/>
    ],
        [
        <MyComponent props={props}/>,
        <MyComponent props={props}/>
    ]
]
```

How can I achieve this? Please refer to the code below on my attempt.

Keep getting following error.

> Error!Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

My attempt to map and create a list of list of components.

Just for reference, MainComponent accepts a list of list under body key as follows:

```
<div>
    {myMap && <MainComponent
        data={{
        body: Object.keys(myMap).map((key) => {
            const categoryArray = myMap[key];
            categoryArray.forEach(category => {
            return {
                content: <div>
                <MyComponent
                    data={{
                        id: category.id,
                        title: category.name,
                        image: {
                            href:`https://domain${category.img}`,
                            alt: category.name,
                        },
                    }}
                />,
                </div>,
            }
            })
        })
        }}
    />}
</div>
```

Comment: You can't return from a [`forEach()`, it returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value). You'll need to use `map()` on the inner loop (and flatten the result if necessary).

Comment: @pilchard I did switch out foreach to a map and got same error. Could you show me an example pls.

Comment: Your specific error implies that `myMap` is not yet defined, so without more code detailing the source of `myMap` it's hard to say.

Comment: @pilchard Think got your point. Not only do I need to switch it to a map, I also need to return the outcome from categoryArray.map itself.